# If a person buys an island in a different country then will he/she has to take Visa for entering his/her island via waterways?

Tags: international, citizenship, non-citizen

If a HNI (High net worth individual) buys an island on a different country for which the individual doesn't has a nationality/citizenship , then does the individual has to take a separate visa for entering his/her own island via waterways (reaching to the nearest point by cruise & then taking a boat ⛵ to reach the island ️) , without actually entering the mainland ?

Note :- This isn't a country specific question , so any examples & counter-examples would do the job.

Comment: Why do you believe they would not be subject to the same travel restrictions as other non-residents? I'm assuming that the owner does not have a dual or citizenship in the country of question? Think of land ownership as "renting from the State/Country"... you "own" it, but it is still part of the country to which it belongs.

Comment: @RonBeyer so does this means that the person has to always take a trip to the country's mainland by taking a visa (if the person doesn't has a dual citizenship) & take a sea route to the island from the mainland ?

Comment: Not necessarily, they may arrange to have customs meet them on the boat or at a designated terminal. Many people travel via private vessel to countries and most countries have a process to process those individuals (and the vessel). Really this may be more appropriate on Travel.SE, [here is a question that is similar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11085/how-do-customs-and-immigration-work-in-a-sailboat) over there.

Comment: @RonBeyer But how can one get customs officers & clearance on a private island . I looked into that link & it was meant for islands or centres with larger population & by definition , those places must be having a customs clearance office , this won't be present on absolutely private island.

Comment: The idea is that you would go to a port with customs first, then head to the private island. Usually countries dictate that you must go through a port of entry. If you are rich enough, you may be able to arrange customs meet you on your island or offshore of your island before you arrive.

Comment: @RonBeyer That sounds like a good solution to me .